# How to set coordination origin to top left instead of center center in ThreeJS?

Tags: three.js

When you add any object to the scene in ThreeJS it is located in the center by default. so that its position is (0,0,0) although it is drawn in the center. I need to make the default position at top left when coordinates are (0,0,0).
Here is a very simple example shows that the default coordinates are center center:
https://jsfiddle.net/qy3572dt/

```js
    
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 80, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.set( 0, 0, 50 );
    
    
    
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    
    
    
    const sprite  = new THREE.Sprite( new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { color: 'red' } ) );
    sprite.position.set(0,0,1);
    scene.add( sprite );
    
    camera.position.z = 5;
    
    var animate = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    };
    
    animate();
```

Comment: Well, if you just need to set the position on top-left, `sprite.position.set` accepts the vector of its position to locally. E.g. [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pr07fmx2/). Unless you want to set the boundary and put it at the very top left of the existing FOV, then it'd need further adjustment.

Comment: You see you used -25 in this statement: sprite.position.set(-25, 10, 0); this means that the coordinate origin is not top left it is center center. What I'm looking for is to have (0,0,0) at the very top left instead of being in the center. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with sprites, just change [Sprite.center](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/Sprite.center).

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(80, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10);
camera.position.z = 5;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const sprite = new THREE.Sprite(new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
  color: 'red'
}));
sprite.center.set(0, 1);
scene.add(sprite);

scene.add(new THREE.AxesHelper());

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.126.1/build/three.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mugen87. But it is still drawn in the center. I need it to be drawn at the top left

Comment: I must say: its not top left. Its center.